# you don't think for one minute I'm going to eat the filth I give to you? what is this mean?

Tags: meaning

It comes from the novel Matilda.

"I'll tell you what I'm talking about, you suppurating little blister!" the Trunchbull shouted.
"Yesterday morning, during break, you sneaked like a serpent into the kitchen and stole a slice of
my private chocolate cake from my tea-tray! That tray had just been prepared for me personally by
the cook! It was my morning snack! And as for the cake, it was my own private stock! That was not
boy's cake! You don't think for one minute I'm going to eat the filth I give to you? That cake was
made from real butter and real cream! And he, that robber-bandit, that safe-cracker, that
highwayman standing over there with his socks around his ankles stole it and ate it!"

you don't think for one minute I'm going to eat the filth I give to you?  what is this mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angry woman, "Trunchbull", is complaining about cake that was stolen from her. She is bragging that it was very high quality cake, made with "butter and real cream".
Apparently this angry woman must provide food for the person she is complaining to, and what she provides is low quality food, "the filth I give to you". She is underlining that she wouldn't eat such filth.

Comment: really thank you